# recreate shell invocation

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, profile

Does a running shell have a mechanism to recreate its invocation?

I sometimes make changes to variables or my profile and have to manually `source` the startup files to make things run again, for example, the `PATH`.

This would mostly apply to interactive shells, I suppose.

I use bash 4 in OS X, but the question is not restricted to these.

Answer (score 3):

I do `exec bash`. It cleans up variables and functions. It shouldn't clean up newly opened file descriptors (with `exec $someNumber<>somefile` ) or exported variables, but I rarely open new files with `exec` and my startup files (which get loaded when you do `exec bash`) restore environment variables I care about (such as `PATH`) to the state I want them in.

(
Doing a plain `bash` has the disadvantage that it'll stick another shell to your current one so then you'll have to `exit` one additional time.
)

If I don't care about cleaning up extra variables and functions, I just re-load the dot files.

I edit `~/.bashrc` and reload it fairly often so I have a keyboard shortuct for the combo:

```
bashrcEdit() { $EDITOR "$HOME/.bashrc"; }
bind -x '"\C-e": bashrcEdit && bashrcReload'
```

and for plain reloading:

```
bind -x '"\C-o": bashrcReload;'
```

---

(
My reload function is:

```
bashrcReload() { unset bashrcSourced; unset PROFILE_SOURCED; source "$HOME/.bashrc"; }
```

instead of just:

```
source "$HOME/.bashrc";
```

It has the `unset`s because those variables (first nonexported—for `.bashrc`, second exported—for `.profile`) serve as double include guards in my setup–without those `unset`s, `source`ing `.bashrc` would be a no-op in my setup.
)

---

## Doing it right

If you want to be thorough, you can

- snapshot the environment at the end of your .bashrc (and then reload it--this you can do perfectly)
- snapshot which filedescriptors are open (and then close all others--this isn't and never can be a perfect solution)

Add this at the end of your `.bashrc`:

```
#Take a snapshot of the env and fds
envSnap() { 
   export FDS="$(/bin/ls /proc/$$/fd/)"
   export ENV="$(export -p)"
}
#Restore env, close extra fds, and re-exec bash
envRestore(){
  exec env - ENV="$ENV" bash --noprofile -c '
    eval "$ENV"
    for fd in `{ /bin/ls /proc/$$/fd; echo "$FDS"; } | sort | uniq -u`; do
       eval "exec $fd>&-"
    done
    exec bash
   '
}
#Take the snapshot now
envSnap
```

Now you can do `envRestore` to pretty much perfectly restore the environment.

E.g., if you do:

```
export FOO=bar
touch file
exec 5<file
```

Then after an `exec bash`, you'll still have:
`/bin/ls /proc/self/fd` include 5, and `echo $FOO` print `bar`.

If you do `envRestore` instead of `exec bash`, however, then `/bin/ls/ /proc/self/fd` shouldn't include 5 (unless your bash usually starts with fd 5 open) and `echo $FOO` should print an empty line.

---

(File descriptors are a weak point of this, because closing the extra filedescriptors doesn't guarantee that the original file descriptors weren't redirected or that the vtable entries they point at haven't been changed in a way that will change how reads or writes on that filedescriptor will behave.)

Comment: I already have an alias in place to `. /etc/profile && . ~/.profile`, but it didn't come to mind `exec`. So for now, it would be a combination of `exec`, `source` and `unset`. Any other additions?

Comment: You could take a snapshot of your environment and your opened fileDeskriptors and then restore those accordingly if you wanted to be perfectly thorough.  Would need to patch env (or make an `env` dumper from scratch) so that the output is shell eval'lable.

Comment: @1.61803 Added info on how to do it if you __really__ wanted to do it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the thoroughness. Albeit, I was searching for a more simple mechanism of self-cleanup — there seems to be none.

Comment: @mikeserv Damn, didn't know about that one. That's a nice replacement for the `envSnapshot` custom-compiled executable! Although now that I wrote the c file, I'm kind of emotionally attached to it.

Comment: @mikeserv Replaced the custom environment snapshotter with `export -p`, thanks mikeserv!

Comment: in most things you can recreate state exactly as you found it - excepting fds *(as you say)* and shell functions *(portably)*. otherwise, local vars can be had w/ `set`, aliases w/ `alias`, environment *(to the extent the shell can reliably duplicate it at all)*, `export -p`, `readonly -p` for read only variables. in `bash` you can get functions as well w/ `declare -fp`.