# running command with the "default" environment

Tags: shell, environment-variables, command

This question https://superuser.com/questions/319043/runing-a-command-without-inheriting-parents-environment suggests that we can run a command without inheriting parent's environment by

```
$ sudo -u "`whoami`" $COMMAND
```

Are there ways to do it without using `sudo`? Since while `sudo` is very popular, it hasn't reach the portable status (or in POSIX) yet.

I have tried `env -i $COMMAND`, but it is no good, since it removes all the environment variables. What I want is to run the command in the **default** environment.

Comment: what are you defining as the default environment?

Comment: @thrig Perhaps the base environment you get when you execute a command with `sudo`...

Comment: @thrig Or the environment you get when you start a new terminal, assuming you do not change your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.

Comment: or a "login" environment?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`login(1)`](http://man.openbsd.org/login.1#ENVIRONMENT) traditionally sets a limited set of environment variables at, well, login time. Like `su` `login` will typically ask for a password even if one logins as oneself so that here is probably not ideal. Unix systems may have additional or different complications, e.g. if there is PAM `pam_env(8)` could add or remove environment variables from what was set by `login`. A copy of what `login(1)` does could thus create a different environment variable set than an actual login through PAM sets.

Then there are terminals and shells; terminals may or may not launch the subsequent process as a "login" shell. Shells may read different files when flagged as login and may end up with different env variables for login vs. non-login instances. [There is existing literature on this topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324359/why-a-login-shell-over-a-non-login-shell).

So based on the unix, the login process, local system configuration, what shell the user uses, and local configuration for that shell there may be different environment variables set "by default."

You may be able to get a suitable list of environment variables with a login shell instance:

```
% export CANARY=tweet
% env -i bash -l -c 'env | grep CANARY'
/Users/jhqdoe/.profile: line 6: set: markdirs: invalid option name
%
```

this does clear environment variables from the parent process (`env | grep CANARY` would be where your `$COMMAND` goes). `.profile` here is actually for `mksh`, not `bash`. However, the above may not set necessary variables that the login workflow sets as it does not go through that code. These might be inspected to see what they are with a new login and then to run:

```
$ env > def
$ env -i bash -l -c 'env > new'
```

And then to compare the `def` and `new` files to see how they differ (possibly involving the `sort` and `diff` commands), then possibly updating the `env` command to set things that are missed before then doing the login shell.

Another idea is to [snapshot the environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244416/recreate-shell-invocation) and use that as the default.

Comment: I didn't know `login` also set environment variables. I always thought it is the shell which does that. Thanks for pointing me to that man page. So it seems using `sudo` is still the easiest way for now.